# Is this pseudocode for implementation of a queue through an array valid?

Tags: arrays, queue, pseudocode, solution

Write a pseudocode on implementing a queue through an array named Q of size n with 1-based indexing( i.e the index of Q starts from 1 instead of the usual 0).

The two functions below called Q.head and Q.tail must be utilized in the code which are described as follows:

Q.head : This function returns the index in the array Q where the next element is to be inserted.

Q.tail : This function returns the index in the array Q where the first element was stored in the beginning.

A precaution must be taken to address the Overflow and Underflow error in the code.

The code provided must have the 3 core functions named Enqueue,Dequeue which are described below:

Enqueue : This function takes two arguments and adds a new element in the queue,

Dequeue : This function takes no element argument and dequeues an element from the queue, following the usual FIFO (First In First Out) ordering.

The book from where I am studying is "Introduction to Algorithms" by  Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein. The thing given in the book is as follows:

In our procedures ENQUEUE and DEQUEUE, we have omitted the error checking for underflow and overflow.

The pseudocode assumes that  n=Q.length.

```
ENQUEUE(Q,x)
1 Q[Q.tail]=x
2 if Q:tail = = Q.length
3 Q:tail=1
4 else Q.tail = Q.tail + 1
DEQUEUE(Q)
1 x=Q[Q.head]
2 if Q.head == Q.length
3 Q.head=1
4 else Q.head = Q.head + 1
5 return x
```

---

As can be seen the above pseudocode uses a circular queue approach to implement the queue through the array Q.

But I think, this makes the question unnecessarily complicated and we can solve this "normally" as well, i.e without implementing a circular queue approach. Hence, I proceeded to write a pseudocode which does not uses the circular queue approach as follows:

```
Enqueue(Q,x)

   if (Q.tail==Q.length +1)

               error overflow

   else

           Q[Q.tail]=x
           Q.tail=Q.tail+1

  Dequeue(Q)

         int  fl=0, x=0

         If (Q.head<=Q.length )

              {

                x=Q[Q.head]

                 fl=1

              }

          If (Q.head<Q.length)

               Q.head=Q.head+1

                return x

          else 

                 print("Queue Empty")
                 error underflow
```

Is the above pseudocode a valid alternative to the approach as given in the book?

If there are any issues with the pseudocode I provided, please do let me know.

Comment: Your algorithm looks totally bogus to me. For starters, you don't even modify the tail when enqueuing! It's unclear what you expect to happen after your queue has allowed N items through. If it's not circular, then what... you just say _"well, I'm empty, but I can't handle any more data, sorry!"_ What the heck is `fl`? The best thing you can do is devise a test for each possible edge case, and then run it through on paper.

Comment: @paddy Your two suggestions where you say, the tail is not modified when enqueuing , and the issue over <fl> is valid and I have already fixed it in my original post and deleted the variable <fl> for it seems unnecessary. However, when the queue has all the n "spaces" filled up, then when someone tries to add a new element in the queue, it simply gives an error "overflow" and this seems *pretty much valid and correct* to me. This is because, if we allow circular queue then underflow error won't ever occur and I think this somewhats violates the traditional definition of a queue.

Comment: You're assuming you'll only ever push a maximum of N items onto the queue. That's not how fixed-size queues work. You should be able to, for example, push N items, pop one and then push one more. Or push and pop items repeatedly forever.

Comment: @paddy But I think then we won't ever get a "queue overflow" error? But the question asks us to handle this error, so I really don't quite get it.  While working with stacks as well, will you also advocate to write the pseudocode so that we can pop or push elements an infinite number of times ?

Answer (score 1):

From the original example, with annotation:

```
ENQUEUE(Q,x)
    Q[Q.tail] = x
    if Q:tail == Q.length
        # not necessarily overflow -- this is just circular wrapping
        Q:tail = 1
    else
        Q.tail = Q.tail + 1
```

```
DEQUEUE(Q)
    x = Q[Q.head]
    if Q.head == Q.length
        # not necessarily underflow -- this is just circular wrapping
        Q.head = 1
    else
        Q.head = Q.head + 1
    return x
```

Note that this is already in contradiction to your statements:

> Q.head : This function returns the index in the array Q where the next element is to be inserted.
>
> Q.tail : This function returns the index in the array Q where the first element was stored in the beginning.

This is wrong. `Q.head` stores the index of the next element that will be *returned* when dequeuing. `Q.tail` stores the index of the next *available* position for an element when enqueuing.

Your task is to detect overflow and underflow. Consider the edge cases first...

Given the above, how do you know the queue is full? Well, `Q.head` must equal to `Q.tail`, because all other "available" positions were already used when you filled the queue. But then how do you know the queue is empty? Because surely that *also* would mean the two are equal.

How to distinguish between them? Use a sentinel value. You can do this however you want. A natural approach would be to consider: *"if 'head' means the position of the next item to dequeue, and the queue is empty, then that value has no meaning"*.

That's a good candidate. You could instead have a special value to represent "pointing nowhere". If the queue is empty, then you set the head to zero. Now you have a real way to tell between full and empty, and you can adjust the algorithm as follows:

```
ENQUEUE(Q,x)
    # Raise error if queue has no available space
    if Q.tail == Q.head
        raise Q.overflow

    # Queue is no longer empty
    if Q.head == 0
        Q.head = Q.tail

    # Push data to queue
    Q[Q.tail] = x
    if Q.tail == Q.length
        Q.tail = 1
    else
        Q.tail = Q.tail + 1
```

```
DEQUEUE(Q)
    # Raise error if queue is empty
    if Q.head == 0
        raise Q.underflow

    # Pop data from queue
    x = Q[Q.head]
    if Q.head == Q.length
        Q.head = 1
    else
        Q.head = Q.head + 1

    # Mark queue empty if we just popped the last item
    if Q.head == Q.tail
        Q.head = 0

    return x
```